# receive string with chars

Tags: python, parsing, endianness

i am quite new in python.

I am receiving (through pyserial) string with data values.
How can I parse these data to particular data structure?

I know that

```
 0-1 byte : id
 2-5 byte : time1 =>but little endian (lsb first)
 6-9 byte : time2 =>but little endian (lsb first)
```

and I looking for a function:

```
def parse_data(string):
  data={}
  data['id'] = ??
  data['time1'] = ??
  data['time2'] = ??
  return data
```

thanks

Comment: This looks like a 64-bit timestamp but you want it as 2 x 32-bit quantities -- are you sure that's what you need?

Comment: @John: Maybe it's a time interval. Anyways, if it's actually a 64 bit timestamp, use the struct format string `Q` (unsigned long long) to get it all.

Comment: @John: Its only example, its really 2x32-bit independent quatities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [struct module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) should be exactly what you're looking for.

```
import struct
# ...
data['id'], data['time1'], data['time2'] = struct.unpack("<HII", string)
```

In the format string, `<` means "interpret everything as little endian, and don't use native alignment", `H` means "unsigned short" and `I` means "unsigned int"

Comment: additional question, what if I have in string: id(2bytes), time1(4bytes), somedata(0-10byte), time2(4bytes).. how can I define unpack()?

Comment: @Meloun: That would depend on how the length of somedata is defined. If it depends on the other bytes in the message, you'll probably have to parse it piece-by-piece since I don't think struct has any mechanism for handling arbitrary variable-length data.

Answer (score 2):

```
import struct
def parse_data(string):
    return dict(zip(['id','time','time2'],struct.unpack("<HII", string)))
```